# Using bank account as account_id on account.move - Odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I need to use the bank account of the company to do an `account.move`.

I've looked into the addons for some example, with the `user_type` field, which is a `Many2one` to model  `account.account.type` , with no luck.

Any example on hoy can I declare it?

I mean, I have methods which create `account.move` but what I need is just an example line on how to declare a bank type account_id.

**EDIT**

Actually, what I need is to use the default company bank account, but still confused on how to declare it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
company = self.env.user.company_id
```

Then:

- `company.bank_ids` will give you all the bank accounts (objects) of the company of the current user.
- `company.bank_ids[0]` will give you the first bank account (the object) found of the company of the current user (it will give you an error if the company doesn't have anyone).
- `company.partner_id.property_account_receivable` will give you the account  (the object) where the company pays its purchases.
- `company.partner_id.property_account_payable` will give you the account (the object) where the company charges its sales.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi @forvas. I'm aware that it's been long time since you posted this answer but I found something useful for what I was looking for and so that I would like to ask you about it.

I'm customising email template and trying to get ban account values. For example, for account number: `${object.company_id.bank_ids.acc_number}`

It works when there is only one bank account but when there are more than one it doesn't work. i used the way you say `bank_ids[0]` and I can get the values of the first one but I want to get values base on their ids. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Here is the question I asked about that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171355/odoo-14-how-to-call-bank-informations-when-there-are-more-than-one-bank-accoun

If you have an idea, I would be much appreciated.